# wxPython on KDE 4.2: popping window on top of the screen and hiding back

Tags: linux, wxpython, kde-plasma

I want my window to be invisible most of the time, but get to top of 
the screen on hotkey and hide again if the user switches to another 
application.

In my hotkey handler I use

```
self.Show() 
self.Raise() 
self.Iconize(False)
```

and in my activate message handler

```
self.Hide() 
self.Iconize(True)
```

but the window pops up on top of the screen, but remains deactivated: 
it's title bar colour is a inactive one, and it flashes in the taskbar 
as a window requiring my attention and it doesn't get EVT_ACTIVATE. I 
tried to add self.SetFocus, but no effect.

And if I use

```
self.Show()  
self.SetFocus()
```

in hotkey handler and in my activate message handler

```
self.Hide()
```

and it works okay if I deactivate my window by clicking to another 
window, but if I press Alt-Tab and then invoke my window with a hotkey 
it doesn't appear on top of the screen but just flashes in the 
taskbar. Also I made an ability to hide it by pressing a button on it, 
and if I hide it this way, it also doesn't show correctly afterwards 
as in the case with Alt-Tab

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a window manager to activate windows. I'm using wmctrl for that purpose (cannot find the same func. through kwin's dbus for kde).